# In Windows, When a new process is started, what windows message is send?

Tags: windows, process, message

In Windows, When a new process is started, what windows message is send ? http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/WinMsgCodes.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if you are asking about a message an app gets when a child process starts. Or if there is a message sent when another process on the same computer starts.  Or if you are asking about a default message every process gets.

But the answer is the same: None.

There are no window messages sent in regards to starting a new process.

What would you do if there was?

Comment: Thank you for response. I means an app when a child process start. I want to use the SetWindowHook method to catch the message when new process started

Comment: Not all processes have windows. Hence, no message pump.  But if you only care about apps with windows, WM_NCCREATE is usually the first message followed by WM_CREATE for a new window.